# Groovy mocking File factory with Spock

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock

I decided to use the File Factory to mock the File object construction.

```
class FileClass {

  def basePath
  def listObjects = []

  def createFilePerObject() {
    listObjects.each {currentObject ->
      // Use some other libraries for mocking(cant run PowerMockito, Gareth Davis adviced me to use JMockit)

      // File currentFile = new File("${basePath.toString()}/${currentObject.objectName}")

      //File factory(The simplest of the solutions)...
      File currentFile = FileFactory.makeFile("${basePath.toString()}/${currentObject.objectName}")

      currentFile.write currentObject.objectContent   //Verify this behaviour!!
    }
  }

}

class SimpleObject {
  String objectName
  String objectContent
}

//Really simple
class FileFactory {
  def static makeFile(String pathFileName) {
    return new File(pathFileName);
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
class FileClassTest extends Specification {

  FileClass fileClass

  def "test simple object"() {

    def listObjects = []

    SimpleObject object1 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "First object", objectContent: "First object content")
    SimpleObject object2 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Second object", objectContent: "Second object content")
    SimpleObject object3 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Third object", objectContent: "Third object content")
    SimpleObject object4 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Fourth object", objectContent: "Fourth object content")

    listObjects << object1
    listObjects << object2
    listObjects << object3
    listObjects << object4

    fileClass = new FileClass(listObjects: listObjects, basePath: ".")

    def mockFile = Mock(File)

    def mockFileFactory = new MockFor(FileFactory)
    mockFileFactory.demand.makeFile {mockFile}    //Return the mocked file...

    when:
    mockFileFactory.use {
      fileClass.createFilePerObject()
    }

    then:
    1 * mockFile.write(_)
  }

}
```

The thing is that it fails with NullPointerException!?

Using the debugger i got to:

```
currentFile.write currentObject.objectContent   //Verify this behaviour!!
```

And, verified, the "current file" really is a mocked file as specified in the test.
"currentObject.objectContent" is not null, "currentFile" is not null.

All of a sudden, it jumps to BaseSpecRunner.java to this method:

```
protected Object invokeRaw(Object target, MethodInfo method, Object[] arguments) {
    if (method.isStub()) return null;

    try {
      return method.getReflection().invoke(target, arguments);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      //Here it fails!
      runStatus = supervisor.error(new ErrorInfo(method, e.getTargetException()));
      return null;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      Error internalError =
          new InternalSpockError("Failed to invoke method '%s'", t).withArgs(method.getReflection().getName());
      runStatus = supervisor.error(new ErrorInfo(method, internalError));
      return null;
    }
  }
```

"InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.". Great.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, you were correct.
The fixed test is here:

```
class FileClassTest extends Specification {

  FileClass fileClass

  def "test simple object"() {

    def listObjects = []

    SimpleObject object1 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "First object", objectContent: "First object content")
    SimpleObject object2 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Second object", objectContent: "Second object content")
    SimpleObject object3 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Third object", objectContent: "Third object content")
    SimpleObject object4 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Fourth object", objectContent: "Fourth object content")

    listObjects << object1
    listObjects << object2
    listObjects << object3
    listObjects << object4

    fileClass = new FileClass(listObjects: listObjects, basePath: ".")

    def mockFile = new MockFor(File)

    //This is how i can verify that the write method was called 4 times(no more, no less)
    // but im not using Spock and some of the advanced verification abilites that come with it...
    mockFile.demand.write(4) {}

    def mockFileFactory = new MockFor(FileFactory)
    mockFileFactory.demand.makeFile(4) {new File(".")}    //Fixed.

    when:
    mockFile.use {
      mockFileFactory.use {
        fileClass.createFilePerObject()
      }
    }
    then:
//    1 * mockFile.write(_)

    //Just pass... Verification is done by MockFor, not Spock
    true
  }
}
```

However, i found this even more "in tune" with my previous testing methodology:

```
class FileClassTest extends Specification {

  class FileCustomWrapper extends File {

    def FileCustomWrapper(String pathname) {
      super(pathname);
    }

    //Ovveride the DefaultGroovyMethods method, Spock can recognize it, its staticly written
    // , and ovveriden only for the use of mocking...

    def write(String s) {
      metaClass.write(s)
      //super.write(s)
    }
  }

  FileClass fileClass

  def "test simple object"() {

    def listObjects = []

    SimpleObject object1 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "First object", objectContent: "First object content")
    SimpleObject object2 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Second object", objectContent: "Second object content")
    SimpleObject object3 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Third object", objectContent: "Third object content")
    SimpleObject object4 = new SimpleObject(objectName: "Fourth object", objectContent: "Fourth object content")

    listObjects << object1
    listObjects << object2
    listObjects << object3
    listObjects << object4

    fileClass = new FileClass(listObjects: listObjects, basePath: ".")

    def mockFile = Mock(FileCustomWrapper)

    def mockFileFactory = new MockFor(FileFactory)
    mockFileFactory.demand.makeFile(4) {mockFile}     //Pass the Spock mock

    when:
    mockFileFactory.use {
      fileClass.createFilePerObject()
    }

    then:
    //You can use the verification...
    4 * mockFile.write(_)
  }
}
```

---

**So, you can use Spock to mock the dynamically added methods by Groovy by overriding them in your custom "wrapper" class.**

Answer (score 4):

Spock doesn't currently support mocking methods like `File.write()` that are dynamically added by Groovy but aren't present in the class. You can solve this problem by using Groovy's `MockFor` instead, like you did for the other mock.

`InvocationTargetException` is an internal Groovy exception. It wraps the `NullPointerException` you are seeing. Spock is smart enough to unwrap the exception for you.